# jQuery hover animations based on viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the process of learning more jQuery and have an issue with some code.
I am attempting to have an animation effect (fadeIn/fadeOut) when the user hovers over a specific element.

However, when the viewport is resized, ie below 480px for mobile display, I need the hover effects to be ignored and just display the call to action. In my code below I am trying to detect the viewport and then apply the appropriate script through an if-then-else statement.

I suspect that I'm not nesting something properly or have a misplaced semi-colon. I've been staring at this a while and am stuck.

I did look at these other posts as reference.

- http://j.mp/1hejP0B
- http://j.mp/1hejRFK

Let me know if you have any questions or can provide additional details.

```
// Script to display div call-to-action over logos

var detectViewPort = function(){
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

// if its bigger than 480px then do the hover effect
    if (viewPortWidth > 480){

// On mouse over logo
    $('.unionlogo').hover(function() {              

// Display the call to action
        $(this).find('a.calltoaction').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
        $(this).find('p.union-name').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
    },
    function() {

// Hide the call to action
        $(this).find('a.calltoaction').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
        $(this).find('p.union-name').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
    });
// if its smaller than 480px then just show the call-to-action
}else{
    $('a.calltoaction').show();
};

$(function(){
  detectViewPort();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   detectViewPort();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look in your console to see what the error message was? As you said, you left off a bracket. You should be formatting your code  a little better, and it would have been obvious.

```
var detectViewPort = function(){
    var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();

    // if its bigger than 480px then do the hover effect
    if (viewPortWidth > 480){

        $('a.calltoaction').hide();
        // On mouse over logo
        $('.unionlogo').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $('.unionlogo').hover(function() {              
            // Display the call to action
            $(this).find('a.calltoaction').stop(false, true).fadeIn(400);
            $(this).find('p.union-name').stop(false, true).fadeOut(400);
        }, function() {
            // Hide the call to action
            $(this).find('a.calltoaction').stop(false, true).fadeOut(400);
            $(this).find('p.union-name').stop(false, true).fadeIn(400);
        });
        // if its smaller than 480px then just show the call-to-action
    } else {
        $('.unionlogo a.calltoaction').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
        $('.unionlogo p.union-name').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
        $('a.calltoaction').show();
        // un bind the hover incase of browser resize
        $('.unionlogo').off('mouseenter mouseleave');


    };
}

$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        detectViewPort();
    });
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   detectViewPort();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reformat. Seemed to fix the initial bug, but for some reason the conditional on the viewport is not being honored still. On viewports less than 480px the hover function is still kicking in.

Comment: Hmm. Try console logging your viewPortWidth after you set it.

Comment: I can now see that the size is below 480px. It's precisely 465px in Firefox using 'Responsive Design View' but the hover function in the example above is still being triggered. Its as if 'viewPortWidth' is not being honored at all.

Comment: See my updates. I've added an unbind to remove the hover handler when the window is less than 480. And I've added a docuemt.ready call, too.

Comment: Hi Nick, the unbind seems to have solved the issue when less than 480px, but when I resize back to a larger viewport the unbinding 'sticks' and then the call-to-action is showing on all the objects. Is there a way to confirm the "bind" on the first part of the conditional, and set things back to what they were?

Comment: This seems weird. Every time you resize it should be calling that function and binding. I've updated the code, give that a try.

Comment: Hi Nick, its not liking that bind in the first instance and not triggering at all. It's really odd that its not working. Need to head out, but I will return. Let me know if you have any other ideas. If not, no worries. I'll most likely have to work this out another way than what I am trying. Thanks for your help and efforts!

Comment: Bizarre. No worries at all. If you have this running live somewhere you can link me and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Nick, I've created a jsfiddle for you to look at. Let me know if you have any ideas on this: http://jsfiddle.net/berchman/tTcV3/1/  You will notice that when you resize the window displaying the ul that not only does the animation break, but it stops performing the smooth fadeIn/fadeOut it does after you refresh/reload. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: Berchman, I've thrown some stuff together and its getting closer, sorry I don't really have much time to spend on this. The only issue is the flashing of the mobile menu when you go below 480. 

Another thing; You should be trying to do this using CSS only, have you tried that? Would be quite easy - You need to use the :hover selector in CSS, have a look into it.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for trying to help out. Really appreciate it. I know I can do this with CSS, but was trying to get something that would support the smooth transitions prior to IE10. Below that IE browser I can't get CSS transitions to work how I want so was trying jQuery to get it done. No worries. Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: No worries at all, mate. Hope you continue on your coding journey! Happy thanksgiving!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a media query to the CSS to hide the original button and add a call to action button when the view port is 480px or less.

Comment: I actually have @media all and (max-width: 480px)... setup to handle the hiding of the p.union-name but the call to action needs to behave differently under different size viewports.